# Python asyncio socket server eating errors (not displaying any errors)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Edited my question to provide more information and a reproducible example.

I'm not sure if anybody could help me here. But I'm having some problems with my asyncio socket server.

As you can see, in the `server.py` on line 18 there is a deliberate line that will cause a value error, as you cannot change "" to an int. This is intentional, as for some reason the error on this line is never output to the console.

When the client connects to the server the `print("here1")` line runs, but the lines after that do not due to the error on line 18. I need this error to be output into console, but it appears nowhere. I am very confused and cannot find anything online about why asyncio could be eating the errors and not displaying them.

I have attempted to see any errors by using the logging module, but even this doesn't show any errors..

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
```

The line which causes the error is definitely running.

I have extracted all of my code into a smaller reproducible set of files below.

server.py

```py
import asyncio


class Server:
    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    async def start_server(self):
        print("Server online")
        server = await asyncio.start_server(self.handle_events, self.host, self.port)
        async with server:
            await server.serve_forever()

    async def handle_events(self, reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter):
        while True:
            print("here1")
            int("")
            print("here2")
            data = await reader.read(1024)
            if not data:
                continue
            print(f"received: {data}")


async def start():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 55551
    server = Server(host=host, port=port)
    server_task = asyncio.create_task(server.start_server())
    await asyncio.gather(server_task)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(start())
```

client.py

```py
import asyncio


class Client:
    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.writer = None
        self.reader = None

    async def start_connection(self):
        self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host=self.host, port=self.port)
        await self.message_handler()

    async def message_handler(self):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            data = await self.reader.read(1024)
            if not data:
                continue

            await self.writer.drain()


async def start():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 55551
    server = Client(host=host, port=port)
    server_task = asyncio.create_task(server.start_connection())
    await asyncio.gather(server_task)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(start())
```

Comment: You must include the code **in the question itself**. External platforms can only be used **in addition** to providing the code in the question. As it stands the external urls can die tomorrow and the question becomes 100% useless to anyone.

Comment: Apologies, have made this changed.

Comment: Just importing logging and setting the logging level won't do anything at all.  You need to catch the error with a try:except: and output a logging message in the except block.  Asyncio may in fact eat errors inside of tasks depending on how the tasks are launched.

Answer (score 0):

Cause it's not even calling that `handle_events` func.

```py
import asyncio

async def tcp_echo_client(message):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        '127.0.0.1', 55555)

    print(f'Send: {message!r}')
    writer.write(message.encode())
    await writer.drain()

    data = await reader.read(100)
    print(f'Received: {data.decode()!r}')

    print('Close the connection')
    writer.close()

asyncio.run(tcp_echo_client('Hello World!'))
```

I just copied this from the doc so I can test it.

Comment: yes it does, I know it is running because it outputs `here1`. And I add the handle_events method into the asyncio start_server method, which means it will run that function whenever a message it received. See:

server = await asyncio.start_server(self.handle_events, self.host, self.port)

Comment: just create client.py and send the requests and you will get the error

Comment: I'm sorry mate, you are not listening to what I have said at all...

Comment: so you wanna get he error before calling ?

Comment: I am calling it. When the client sends a request or connects to the server it runs the handle events method. I have not included the client connection because it is not really relevant, since the error is not happening in the client.